# WebAssembly: Is it possible to use 2x i32.store instead of one i64.store?

Tags: memory, stack, webassembly

If there is an i64 on the stack, is it possible to use two `i32.store` to subsequent memory indices to write the i64 to memory? Or is this not a valid module anymore?

```
==i32==|==i32==

======i64======
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two subsequent i32.store operations are valid, as long as you have two values on the stack. But the net result will not be the same as an i64.store. You will instead need to perform a shift operation to store the lower then the upper bytes.

```
;; the value to store 
i64.const 0x11223344556677
;; storage offset
i32.const 0
;; store
i32.store

;; load the value again 
i64.const 0x11223344556677
;; the number of bits to shift by
i32.const 32
;; shift
i32.shr_u
;; storage offset
i32.const 4
;; store
i32.store
```

You’d probably use a local to avoid loading the same number twice.

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a dup opcode yet :(

Comment: You don’t need one, if you wrap the above in a function, you can use get_local to obtain the i64 value to store each time

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot assume that stack operands lie in contiguous memory -- or in memory at all, since in reality they will typically live in separate CPU registers. So implicitly "merging" two i32 operands from the operand stack as if they were a single i64 is not possible. You need to store them separately. Similarly, the other way round.